# Rotated shape is moving on y-axis when resizing shape width

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to resize a rotated shape on canvas. My problem is that when I call the rendering function, the shape starts "drifting" depending on the shape angle. How can I prevent this?

I've made a simplified fiddle demonstrating the problem, when the canvas is clicked, the shape is grown and for some reason it drifts upwards.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5gxo1p7/

```
<style>
    canvas {
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height= 150;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var counter = 0;

    var shape = {
        top: 120,
        left: 120,
        width: 120,
        height: 60,
        rotation: Math.PI / 180 * 15
    };



    function draw() {
        var h2 = shape.height / 2;
        var w2 = shape.width / 2;

        var x = w2;
        var y = h2;


        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.translate(75,37.5)
        ctx.translate(x, y);

        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * 15);
        ctx.translate(-x, -y);

        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, shape.width, shape.height);
        ctx.restore();
}


canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {

    shape.width = shape.width + 15;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw.bind(this));
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw.bind(this));
</script>
```

In the "real" code the shape is resized when the resize-handle is clicked and moved but I think this example demonstrates the problem sufficiently.

EDIT: updated fiddle to clarify the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/x5gxo1p7/9/

Comment: It's drifted due to `ctx.translate(x, y);` and `ctx.translate(-x, -y);`. Try commenting them out! - https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/x5gxo1p7/3/

Comment: I need the translates to rotate the shape around its center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, problem was that I wasn't calculating the new center point coordinates.

The new fiddle with solution: https://jsfiddle.net/HTxGb/151/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width =500;
canvas.height = 500;

var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var rectw = 20;
var recth = 20;
var rectx = -rectw/2;
var recty = -recth/2;
var rotation = 0;
var addedRotation = Math.PI/12;
var addedWidth = 20;
var addedHeight = 10;

var draw = function() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  ctx.fillRect(rectx, recty, rectw, recth);
  ctx.restore();
}


document.getElementById('growXRight').addEventListener('click', function() {
  rectx -= addedWidth/2;
  x += addedWidth/2 * Math.cos(rotation);
  y -= addedWidth/2 * Math.sin(-rotation);
  rectw += addedWidth;
  draw();
})

document.getElementById('growXLeft').addEventListener('click', function() {
  rectx -= addedWidth/2;
  x -= addedWidth/2 * Math.cos(rotation);
  y += addedWidth/2 * Math.sin(-rotation);
  rectw += addedWidth;
  draw();
})

document.getElementById('growYTop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  recty -= addedHeight/2;
  x += addedHeight/2 * Math.sin(rotation);
  y -= addedHeight/2 * Math.cos(-rotation);
  recth += addedHeight;
  draw();
})

document.getElementById('growYBottom').addEventListener('click', function() {
  recty -= addedHeight/2;
  x -= addedHeight/2 * Math.sin(rotation);
  y += addedHeight/2 * Math.cos(-rotation);
  recth += addedHeight;
  draw();
})

document.getElementById('rotatePlus').addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotation += addedRotation;
  rotation = rotation % (Math.PI*2);
  if(rotation % Math.PI*2 < 0) {
    rotation += Math.PI*2;
  }
  draw();
})

document.getElementById('rotateMinus').addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotation -= addedRotation;
  rotation = rotation % (Math.PI*2);
  if(rotation % Math.PI*2 < 0) {
    rotation += Math.PI*2;
  }
  draw();
})

draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always use local coordinates to define shapes.**

When rendering content that is intended to be transformed the content should be in its own (local) coordinate system. Think of a image. the top left pixel is always at 0,0 on the image no matter where you render it. The pixels are at their local coordinates, when rendered they are moved to the (world) canvas coordinates via the current transformation.

So if you make your shape with coordinates set to its local, making the rotation point at its local origin (0,0) the display coordinates are stored separately as world coordinates

```
var shape = {
    top: -30,   // local coordinates with rotation origin 
    left: -60,  // at 0,0
    width: 120,
    height: 60,
    world : {
         x : canvas.width / 2,
         y : canvas.height / 2,
         rot : Math.PI / 12,   // 15deg clockwise
    }
};
```

Now you don't have to mess about with translating forward and back... blah blah total pain.

Just

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(shape.world.x,shape.world.y);
ctx.rotate(shape.world.rot);
ctx.fillRect(shape.left, shape.top, shape.width, shape.height)
ctx.restore();
```

or event quicker and eliminating the need to use save and restore

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,shape.world.x,shape.world.y);
ctx.rotate(shape.world.rot);
ctx.fillRect(shape.left, shape.top, shape.width, shape.height);
```

The local shape origin (0,0) is where the transformation places the translation.

This greatly simplifies a lot of the work that has to be done

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 150;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;  


var shape = {
    top: -30,   // local coordinates with rotation origin 
    left: -60,  // at 0,0
    width: 120,
    height: 60,
    world : {
         x : canvas.width / 2,
         y : canvas.height / 2,
         rot : Math.PI / 12,   // 15deg clockwise
     }
};

function draw() {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // to clear use default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // you were scaling the shape, that can be done via a transform
    // once you have moved the shape to the world coordinates.
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,shape.world.x,shape.world.y);
    ctx.rotate(shape.world.rot);
 
    // after the transformations have moved the local to the world
    // you can ignore the canvas coordinates and work within the objects
    // local. In this case showing the unscaled box
    ctx.strokeRect(shape.left, shape.top, shape.width, shape.height);
    // and a line above the box
    ctx.strokeRect(shape.left, shape.top - 5, shape.width, 1);
 
    ctx.scale(0.5,0.5); // the scaling you were doing
    ctx.fillRect(shape.left, shape.top, shape.width, shape.height);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
    shape.width += 15;
    shape.left -= 15 / 2;
    shape.world.rot += Math.PI / 45; // rotate to illustrate location 
                                     // of local origin
    var distToMove = 15/2;
    shape.world.x += Math.cos(shape.world.rot) * distToMove;
    shape.world.y += Math.sin(shape.world.rot) * distToMove;
    draw();
});
// no need to use requestAnimationFrame (RAF) if you are not animation 
// but its not wrong. Nor do you need to bind this (in this case
// this = window) to the callback RAF does not bind a context
// to the callback 
/*window.requestAnimationFrame(draw.bind(this));*/
requestAnimationFrame(draw); // functionaly identical
// or just
/*draw()*/ //will work
```

```css
 body { font-family : Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size : 12px; color : #242729;} /* SO font currently being used */

canvas { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p>Click to grow "and rotate" (I add that to illustrate the local origin)</p>
<p>I have added a red box and a line above the box, showing how using the local coordinates to define a shape makes it a lot easier to then manipulate that shape when rendering "see code comments".</p>
```

Comment: Very nice answer, yet it doesn't solve the problem. I need to grow the shape only in one direction, yet rotate around its "new" center. In your example the shape rotates around it's old center point when I remove the shape.left -= 15 / 2.

Comment: @Jomppe If you want to grow it and move along its direction. Add distance to move to the world coords with `world.x += Math.cos(world.rot) * dist; world.y += Math.sin(world.rot) * dist;`

Comment: @Jomppe I have updated the answer snippet to show movement in the world space along the shapes x axis.

Comment: I do not want it to move, I only want to resize it. I've updated my original post with a new fiddle, which hopefully demonstrates the problem better.

Comment: @Jomppe Sorry I do not understand. If your update is what you want then your problem is solved?

Comment: The problem isn't solved, see the fiddle. Try to grow one of the rotated shapes, see that they move on the y-axis.

Comment: @Jomppe I looked at the fiddle it does not explain what you want. Please provide a detailed explanation of what you want to happen. We can not read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You had ctx.translate() used where it was not entirely necessary. That caused the problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 150;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var counter = 0;

var shape = {
    top: 120,
    left: 120,
    width: 120,
    height: 60,
    rotation: Math.PI / 180 * 15
};

function draw() {

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(75,37.5)

    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * 15);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, shape.width, shape.height);
    ctx.restore();
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {

    shape.width = shape.width + 15;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw.bind(this));
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw.bind(this));
</script>
```

Comment: I need to rotate the shape around its center so I need to translate to the shape's center point.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `x` and `y` are set as the half value of the shape size, which completely changes its position.

You should set a point for the center of the shape, anyway. I set this point as `ctx.canvas.[width or height] / 2`, the half of the canvas.

```
var h2 = shape.height / 2;
var w2 = shape.width / 2;

var x = (ctx.canvas.width / 2) - w2;
var y = (ctx.canvas.height / 2) - h2;

ctx.save();

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.translate(x + (shape.width / 2), y + (shape.height / 2));

ctx.rotate(((shape.rotation * Math.PI) / 180) * 15);

ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillRect(-shape.width / 2, -shape.height / 2, shape.width, shape.height);
ctx.restore();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5gxo1p7/7/).